# Assign a Checkbox with a specific value Visual Basic 2010

Tags: checkbox, assign, basic

I'm trying to figure out how I would assign a checkbox to have a specific value that I can use in a calculation.

Here's what I have so far (Sorry for how bad this is, i'm a beginner O.o)

```
  Dim box1 As Integer
    Dim box2 As Integer
    Dim Answer As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        box1 = TextBox1.Text
        box2 = TextBox2.Text
        TextBoxAnswer.Text = box1 - box2 (And I need to add a divide here with the value of a checkbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I assume that you meant "Textbox" if this is not the case just write a comment and I will edit this answer.
Lets just go at it piece by piece

```
    box1 = TextBox1.Text
    box2 = TextBox2.Text
    TextBoxAnswer.Text = box1 - box2 (And I need to add a divide here with the value of a checkbox)
```

A string is letters (like "Hello" is a string)
An integer is a number (like 2422)
If a string contains number like "322" you can convert it to an integer.
You can convert an integer to a string.
To convert you can just do this "string = number" or "number = string"
This isn't the best way to do it but it works well as long as the string is only numbers, and has no whitespace characters (like a tab)
This being said, TextBox1.Text is a string, so it must be only numbers if you are going to do calculation with it.
**You can do things like intNumber1 = intNumber1 + 1, which would increase the value of variable intNumber1 by 1**
So here is a modified code that would work with your example, assuming everything is how it seems from your vaguely worded question

```
    box1 = TextBox1.Text
    box2 = TextBox2.Text
    TextBoxAnswer.Text = (box1 - box2) / TextBoxAnswer.Text
```

You can use the () to order the math so the stuff in the parentheses is done first.
**ALL OF THAT BEING SAID I RECOMMEND NOT USING A TEXTBOX FOR CALCULATIONS**
There are so many better ways to do calculations, and if you plan on having the ability to use decimals, you will have a much easier time doing math with doubles or integers than with a textbox. Variables can be used for lots of things, but they are definitely **THE** way to do calculations like the one you had so you could do this instead

```
    Dim intAnswer As Integer
    Dim box1 As Integer = TextBox1.Text
    Dim box2 As Integer = TextBox2.Text
    'The following area assumes that the textbox is STRICTLY NUMBERS
    intAnswer = TextBoxAnswer.Text
    intAnswer = (box1 - box2) / intAnswer
    TextBoxAnswer.Text = intAnswer
```

You should also note that doing division with integers will cause them to round, often resulting in an undesired output from your program.
**The best thing to do with a TextBox is to use it to accept input and put out output, not using it for calculations**